# SQL command to group field and create new column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table: `name, date, url, no`, `url` includes `"facebook","twitter","other"`.

How can I generate a new table: `date, facebook, twitter, total, unique name`, such that, grouping by date, `facebook` field is the sum of the `no` WHERE `url="facebook"`, and same as `twitter`; `total` field is the sum of the `no` of all; `unique name` counts the distinct `name` number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use SUM/CASE for this.

```
SELECT Date,
       SUM(case when url = 'facebook' then no else 0 end) as facebook,
       SUM(case when url = 'twitter' then no  else 0 end) as twitter,
       SUM(no) total,
       COUNT(DISTINCT NAME) as `unique name`
FROM
      table
GROUP BY
      date
```

Comment: `facebook`,`twitter`,`total` are the sum of `no` instead of count. And why GROUP BY `name`?

Comment: How to count the distinct name?

Comment: Can you answer my other question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072053/sql-update-on-duplicate-key-update